# Partitioning a seq - Recursion in Clojure (or Lisp in general)

Tags: recursion, clojure, lisp

In a project I'm working on I came across an interesting problem that I'm curious about other solutions for. I'm in the middle of reading "The Little Schemer" so I'm trying out some recursion techniques. I'm wondering if there is another way to do this with recursion and also interested if there is an approach without using recursion.

The problem is to take a sequence and partition it into a seq of seqs by taking every nth element. For example this vector:

```
[ :a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i ]
```

when partitioned with n=3 would produce the seq

```
((:a :d :g) (:b :e :h) (:c :f :i))
```

and with n=4:

```
((:a :e :i) (:b :f) (:c :g) (:d :h))
```

and so on. I solved this using two functions. The first creates the inner seqs and the other pulls them together. Here are my functions:

```
(defn subseq-by-nth
  "Creates a subsequence of coll formed by starting with the kth element and selecting every nth element."
  [coll k n]
  (cond (empty? coll) nil
        (< (count coll) n) (seq (list (first coll)))
        :else (cons (nth coll k) (subseq-by-nth (drop (+ n k) coll) 0 n))))

(defn partition-by-nth
  ""
  ([coll n]
     (partition-by-nth coll n n))
  ([coll n i]
      (cond (empty? coll) nil
        (= 0 i) nil
        :else (cons (subseq-by-nth coll 0 n) (partition-by-nth (rest coll) n (dec i))))))
```

I'm not completely happy with the partition-by-nth function having multiple arity simply for the recursion, but couldn't see another way.

This seems to work just fine with all the test cases. Is this a decent approach? Is it too complicated? Is there a way to do this without recursion or maybe in a single recursive function?

Thanks for the suggestions. I'm new to both Clojure and Lisp, so am picking up the different techniques as I go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I expect there is a simpler recursive definition which is more in the spirit of *The Little Schemer*, but the following function using `take-nth` is quite a bit more compact, since you said you were interested in alternative approaches:

```
(defn chop [coll n]
  (for [i (range n)]
    (take-nth n (drop i coll))))
```

which satisfies your examples:

```
(chop [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i ] 3)
;= ((:a :d :g) (:b :e :h) (:c :f :i))

(chop [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i ] 4)
;= ((:a :e :i) (:b :f) (:c :g) (:d :h))
```

In Clojure, the built in libraries will get you surprisingly far; when that fails, use an explicitly recursive solution.  This version is also lazy; you'd probably want to use `lazy-seq` or `loop...recur` in any "longhand" (explicitly recursive) version to handle large datasets without blowing the stack.

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome! I had no idea it could be that easy. Just when I think I'm starting to understand this I'm shown how little I really do.

Comment: @DaveKincaid: You should try to model your solution using existing high order functions rather then using recursion and you will certainly be able to come up with this kind of concise solutions :)

Comment: I usually try to do that, but there is so much there it's hard to find the particular function that you want if you haven't used it before. It looks like what I did was re-implement the take-nth function. Not the first time I've re-implemented a core Clojure function. At least each one is a good learning experience.

Comment: This is a Shlemiel-the-painter, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Edited because the original answer totally missed the point.

When I first saw this question I thought clojure.core function `partition` applied (see 
[ClojureDocs page](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition)).

As Dave pointed out partition only works on the elements in the original order. The `take-nth` solution is clearly better. Just for the sake of interest a combination of map with multiple sequences derived from partition kind-of works.

```
(defn ugly-solution [coll n]
  (apply map list (partition n n (repeat nil) coll)))

(ugly-solution [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i] 3)
;;=> ((:a :d :g) (:b :e :h) (:c :f :i))
(ugly-solution [:a :b :c :d :e :f :g :h :i] 4)
;;=> ((:a :e :i) (:b :f nil) (:c :g nil) (:d :h nil))
```

Comment: I saw that, but couldn't figure out how to use it in this case. It seemed to always partition keeping the elements in the same order. If you have a way to do it, I'd be interested in seeing it too.

Comment: @DaveKincaid yes, you are quite right. The reordering requirement means partition doesn't work. I have edited the answer to use partition but take-nth is definitely the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have to offer this Common Lisp loop:

```
(defun partition-by-nth (list n)
  (loop :with result := (make-array n :initial-element '())
        :for i :upfrom 0
        :and e :in list
        :do (push e (aref result (mod i n)))
        :finally (return (map 'list #'nreverse result))))
```